# How can I find nearest neighbors of points in a data frame from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, knn

I want to find `k` nearest neighbors of all points in dataframe `A` from a dataframe `B`. How is that doable?
It seems `sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors` takes only one set of data, and just one query point.

Like:

```
samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
neigh.fit(samples) 

print(neigh.kneighbors([[1., 1., 1.]]))
```

from [Python documentaion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.fit)

I want to have a data frame with more than one query point instead of `[[1., 1., 1.]]`

P.S. I want the metric to be `Mahalanobis` which `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree` does not accept, and `scipy.spatial.KDTree`even does not have any metric option.

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

dataA = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(100, 100))
dataB = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(100, 100))

kdB = KDTree(dataB.values)
print(kdB.query(dataA.values, k=3)[-1]) # k desired number of neighbors 
#returns indices of 3-neighbors for all rows/points in A
```

Comment: Thank you @bubble, I need the metric to be Mahalanobis.

Comment: May be [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) would be useful; it supports custom distances

Comment: Thank you so much, but I want to make sure the indcies are the indcies of 3 points in B which are the nearest to all points in A?